# Prove $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{3k+2} = \frac{1}{9}\left(\sqrt{3}\pi-3\ln\,2\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Just for fun:

How can we prove (calculate) that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{3k+2} = \frac{1}{9}\left(\sqrt{3}\pi-3\ln\,2\right)$ ? Can we use (9) from:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html

(9): $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{3k+1} = \frac{1}{9}\left(\sqrt{3}\pi+3\ln\,2\right)$

?

Thx!

Comment: Please include what $(9)$ says, don't link to it.  (You seem to have a good enough grasp of mathjax to format as necessary)

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes thesource and motivation of the problem, your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We can evaluate the series of interest without appealing to the Digamma Function.

Note that we can simply write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{2N}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{3n+2}&=\sum_{n=0}^N\left(\frac{1}{6n+2}-\frac{1}{6n+5}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^N\int_0^1\left( x^{6n+1}-x^{6n+6}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 x\left(\frac{1-x^{6N+6}}{1+x^3}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x}{1+x^3}\right)\,dx -\int_0^1 x^{6N+7} \left(\frac{1}{1+x^3}\right)\,dx
\end{align}$$

Applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem (or alternatively, integrate by parts and observe that the second integral is $ O(N^{-1})$), we find that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{3n+2}=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^3}\,dx$$

Can you finish now using partial fraction expansion for example?

Comment: I need to learn a bit more this kind of method to sum up series!

Comment: Yes, the integral is easy. Very nice! Thanks a lot, Mark!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure David.

Comment: I just have a quick question, but is there any advantage over using$$\int\limits_0^1 dx\, x^n=\frac 1{n+1}$$than$$\int\limits_0^{\infty}dx\, e^{-nx}=\frac 1n$$? Why’d you choose the former over the latter?

Comment: @frankw.  My choice seemed more natural.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over 3k + 2} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{\expo{\ic\pi/3}}^{3k} \over 3k + 2} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{\expo{\ic\pi/3}}^{k} \over k + 2}
\,{1 + \expo{2k\pi\ic/3} + \expo{-2k\pi\ic/3} \over 3}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 3}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic k\pi/3} + \pars{-1}^{k} +
\expo{-\ic k\pi/3} \over k + 2} =
{2 \over 3}\,\Re\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic k\pi/3} \over k + 2} +
{1 \over 3}\,\Re\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k + 2}
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over 3}\,\Re\pars{\expo{-2\pi\ic/3}\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic k\pi/3} \over k}} +
{1 \over 3}\,\Re\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k}
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over 3}\,\Re\pars{-\expo{-\ic\pi/3} +
\expo{-2\pi\ic/3}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic k\pi/3} \over k}} +
{1 \over 3}\pars{1 + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k}}
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over 3}\braces{-\,{1 \over 2} -
\Re\bracks{\expo{-2\pi\ic/3}\ln\pars{1 - \expo{\ic\pi/3}}}} +
{1 \over 3}\braces{1 - \ln\pars{1 - \bracks{-1}}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 3}\ln\pars{2} - {2 \over 3}\,\Re\bracks{%
-\,{1 + \root{3}\ic \over 2}
\ln\pars{{1 \over 2} - {\root{3} \over 2}\,\ic}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 3}\ln\pars{2} - {2 \over 3}\,\Re\bracks{%
-\,{1 + \root{3}\ic \over 2}
\pars{-\,{\pi \over 3}\,\ic}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{-\,{1 \over 3}\ln\pars{2} + {\root{3} \over 9}\,\pi} \approx 0.3736
\end{align}